# getting user IP, user_agent,refferer via websocket

Tags: javascript, php, html, websocket

I'm trying use websocket to my project. 
to implement I've used this code http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket.

this chat works good, but in my project I must get statistics about visited user on webpage, so I need user IP, User_Agent, user referrer to recognize user.

My question is, how to get all this necessary data (user IP,browser user agent, refferer) via websocket?

**And one more:** to improve performance will better to use move code from php websocket to node.js with nginx server?

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript at the client side, which will send this info using websocket.sendMessage() after the upgrade handshake.
And then you can maintain some data struture that would store that info w.r.t the session id of the client at the server side if you want to.

Comment: yes I understand that is possible to send everything but question is how to get this data in client side before send? the best will  some example how to get this all info like IP user, user_agent, refferer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getip(json) {
            alert(json.ip); // alerts the ip address
        }
    </script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="http://jsonip.appspot.com/?callback=getip">
    </script>
```

The `getip()` method alerts the client IP as soon as the page is loaded.
You can now store the IP in a variable and send it to the server using websocket's `send()` method.

For browser UA, please read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent).